# Highlight whole row regardless rowpsan - css

Tags: html, css

I have the code below:

```css
 tbody > tr:hover{
  background-color: lightgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<table border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">January</td>
    <td>Week 1</td>
    <td >$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Week 3</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">February</td>
    <td>Week 2</td>
    <td >$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Week 1</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I highlight the whole row when I hover to the row.

For example, when I hover to January, it should highlight the whole January row instead of highlight only the half one because of the rowspan attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Move the styling to the `td` under the hovered `tr`. In addition, highlight the sibling row, when the 1st row is hovered. The only caveat is that if the 2nd `tr` is hovered, it won't highlight the 1st cell.

```css
tr:hover > td {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr:nth-child(2n + 1):hover + tr {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
      <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">January</td>
      <td>Week 1</td>
      <td>$150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Week 3</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">February</td>
      <td>Week 2</td>
      <td>$50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Week 1</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will try to look other solution for highlight that first row...

Answer (score 0):

```css
tr:hover td:not([rowspan]) {background: red;}
  tr:hover td[rowspan]:hover ~ td {background: none;}
tr:hover td[rowspan]:hover {background: yellow;}
```

```html
<table border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">January</td>
    <td>Week 1</td>
    <td >$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Week 3</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">February</td>
    <td>Week 2</td>
    <td >$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Week 1</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, is it possible to highlight the first cell as well, I mean the "January" or "February"...

Comment: @helloworld1234 now check it. tr:hover td[rowspan]:hover {background: yellow;} to highlight the "January" or "February".